# How to make ASP.Net run in Managed (v4.0.30319), x86 mode to enable remote debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug some code running on a server using the Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger. I can get connected and view all the running processes but when I try to connect to the w3wp.exe process it is having none of it.

From my fiddling I've noticed that it will connect to apps that are running in the Managed (v4.0.30319), x86 mode, however if it's just x86 it doesn't connect and I'm guessing this is because it's been compiled and isn't in MSIL.

I've copied over the files from my machine, by passing all the precompilation that we were doing, as much config set to debug as I can find and even still when I try to attach it still reports x86 with no mention of any managed code.

Just to clarify, this is what I see when attaching on my local machine:
[image: Local Attach to Process Window]

And this is the same app running on the remote server:
[image: Remote Attach to Process Window]

Does anyone know how to force the server to run in managed mode, or is there another reason I can't connect to the remove debugger?

Thanks

Comment: Try to access some ASP.NET pages or contents to trigger w3wp.exe to load CLR. When it only shows x86, it means that CLR is not yet loaded.

Comment: @LexLi I've tried loading a number of pages and it's still showing up as x86. Built the solution to target Any CPU if that makes any difference.